# Creating a new DataFrame variable: TypeError 'DataFrame' Object not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to using python and hoping someone could help with a seemingly simple problem.

I have an existing dataframe where I've created a new variable called 'REGION'. As an example, I did so in the following manner:

```
weatherFileDailyJoin['REGION'] = 0


Arizona = weatherFileDailyJoin['STATE_NAME'] == 'Arizona'
Colorado = weatherFileDailyJoin['STATE_NAME'] == 'Colorado'
Idaho  = weatherFileDailyJoin['STATE_NAME'] == 'Idaho'

weatherFileDailyJoin.loc[Arizona,'REGION'] = 'West' 
weatherFileDailyJoin.loc[Colorado,'REGION'] = 'West' 
weatherFileDailyJoin.loc[Idaho,'REGION'] = 'West'
```

I have another pre-existing variable called 'YEAR'. I would like to create a new variable called 'REGION_YEAR'. I try to do so in the following way:

```
 weatherFileDailyJoin['REGION_YEAR'] = weatherFileDailyJoin('REGION') + '_' + weatherFileDailyJoin['YEAR'].map(str)
```

I get the TypeError: `'DataFrame' object is not callable.` I believe the problem lies in my construction of the 'REGION' variable. I've created other new variables using 'YEAR' and other existing variables in the same manner with no problem. Any ideas on how to make the 'REGION' variable a callable object so that I can create the 'REGION_YEAR' variable?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired final output dataframe?

Comment: Is `weatherFileDailyJoin('REGION')` intentional or mistake?

Comment: @JoeR - I would like to maintain the existing DataFrame I am currently working with. I would only like to add 2 new column variables. The first being 'REGION' which I create using an existing column. Second, the variable 'REGION_YEAR' which would be using the 'REGION' variable and the existing 'YEAR' variable. An example entry of what I would like 'REGION_YEAR' to look like would be 'West_1978'.

Comment: @Psidom That is intentional. I intended to create a new column, 'REGION' and fill in the values of that column with the following code.

Comment: I mean it should be square brackets instead of parentheses?

Comment: Your code lacks python/pandas structure, you should go through a basic python/pandas tutorial.

Comment: @Psidom - wow, thank you that was actually my issue...